# Specify seconds in Tasks Scheduler

Tags: windows

My command line is:

```
schtasks /Create /SC ONCE /ST 00:00:30 /TN MyApp /TR notepad.exe
```

But the task initializes at 00:00, Why ignores the 30 seconds?

My operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: What happens if you use e.g. 00:05:00? Is it still ignored?

Answer (score 2):

From the output of `schtasks /create ?`:

```
  /ST   starttime    Specifies the start time to run the task. The time
                  format is HH:mm (24 hour time) for example, 14:30 for
                  2:30 PM. Defaults to current time if /ST is not
                  specified.  This option is required with /SC ONCE.
```

As you can see there are no seconds in the format of the /ST parameter.